# Display 'State' value in Checkout ONLY if Billing Information is complete - LemonStand

Tags: php

Using **LemonStand,** I am  using the following snippet to display the State name in my '**checkout summary**' partial in the sidebar:

`<?=Shop_CountryState::create()->find_by_id($billing_info->state)->name;?><br />`

However, before I have even selected my State, it displays 'Alabama' in this area.

Is there a way to disable running the above code until both Billing and Shipping Information have been completed in the Checkout?

Thank you

Comment: Is "alabama" the default state in the `select`? Also, to answer your question, **Yes.** It's called an `if` statement. Just set a flag and test it.

Comment: Hey Matt. Only when 'United States' is selected does it then pre-fill the 'State' column where 'Alabama' is first.
Better example is that 'Afghanistain' is also displaying as default even though I haven't selected my Country yet.

Comment: Understand I've to use a conditional but no idea how to within the code. How do I know when the user is on Stage 3 of the Checkout. The URL doesn't change as it uses AJAX.

Comment: That's because they're the first values in the list of available states/countries. If you don't want them to display, put a default value as the first option `<option value='0'>Select [State/Country]</option>`. Easy.

Comment: Hmm...OK. Good call. Where do I add this in my LemonStand app?

Comment: Today was the first time I had even heard of LemonStand. Sorry, I can't help you there.

Comment: Aaah, that's OK :-)
I'll ask over at the LS forums too - thanks anyway :)